# Section header text appearing one page early in a specific situation

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

Due to specific reasons, I created an alternative `\section` command called `\nsection`. The simplified version below should behave similarly to the original `\section` command, however, I get an unexpected behavior regarding the header text.

When I use `\nsection` at a place where page-break occurs, the header text appears **one page too early**. In the example below, the `title D` header should appear only on page 4, but it appears already on page 3. Apparently, the original `\section` command does something to prevent this behavior, as the `title C` header does not appear on page 2.

I am interested in knowing why this happens and how to configure my custom command to prevent it.

I realized, that calling `\clearpage` before my `\nsection` solves the issue, however, this would result in unwanted behavior if placed anywhere but the page break.

[image]

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\nsection}{oom}{%
    \section*{#3}
    \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\sffamily \slshape #3}    
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\section{title A}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{title B}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{title C}
\lipsum[1-4]
\nsection{title D}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the first question to be asked should be: Are all of those section (in general) be unnumbered? Why aren't you using the mark mechanism? `\markright{Wombat title}`

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/ might be suited for you.

Comment: @Johannes_B In this case yes, the sections will be unnumbered. Using `\markright` actually helped, thanks! But I don't understand why it helped, what are the `\markright` and `\rightmark` commands doind to prevent this. Could you please point me in the right direction? Also, what would change if the sections would not be unnumbered in general?

Comment: If the sections are all unnumbered, use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` in the preamble and use regular `\section`  commands (without the asterisk). Concerning the marks: That is just what you are supposed to use; because it is working. I never checked what happens internally, but it will be a bit complex due to (La)TeX's asymetrical workings.